# Launch Error "Provider com.sun.xml.... not found" in Eclipse PTP

Tags: debugging, parallel-processing, eclipse-cdt

It's too hard to debug a MPI program using GDB. I've tried to buy parallel debugger but failed .
I found Eclipse has a parallel debug plugin(Eclipse PTP or Eclipse science),but I can't use it!

I'm using:

```
ubuntu 18.04 
openJDK 11.0.2
eclipse-parallel 2019-03-R
```

When I setting run>run configurations:

```
1.Target System Configuration:Generic OpenMPI Interactive
2.Connection Type:Local
```

error occur

Launch Error:

```
Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory not found
Reason:com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory cannot be found
by org.eclipse.ptp.rm.jaxb.core_1.2.0.201811201954
```

I've tried to download different version of eclipse:

eclipse before 2017:I can't open it ,there is something wrong with openJDK 11

eclipse-parallel-photon-R: When i click "local" in configuration,nothing happened...

Comment: Try with Oracle jdk instead of openJdk

Comment: @greywolf82 Thanks for your reply. I've changed openJDK to Oracle jdk,but it come out with the same error....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had same problem. If you still suffer / somebody has the same problem, it seems it is fixed in the latest version 201906. You can download using installer from:

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2019-06/M2/eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz

Comment: Were you able to debug healthily using version 201906? I have problem with debugging.